# Terraform docker_container labels not working?

Tags: docker, terraform

I'm trying to add labels to a docker container with terraform.  The [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/container.html) says to use 'labels'.  I've tried:

```
resource "docker_container" "my_test" {
  image = "ubuntu:latest"
  name = "my_test"
  labels {
    first = "label 1"
    another = "label 2"
  }
}
```

But I get

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on dock.tf line 4, in resource "docker_container" "my_test":
   4:   labels {

Blocks of type "labels" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"labels"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.
```

I'm using Terraform v0.12.9 + provider.docker v2.3.0.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `labels` is an attribute in this instance. The syntax to set these blocks changed in Terraform 0.12.x.

The resource reference you linked is still showing the pre 0.12.x method. You can tell by the way the image attribute references the docker_image resource: `image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"`

Note the `labels = {`:

```
resource "docker_container" "my_test" {
  image = "ubuntu:latest"
  name = "my_test"
  labels = {
    first = "label 1"
    another = "label 2"
  }
}
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#attributes-vs-blocks